# Proving Chi-squared Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have some problems solving the following problem:

Let $X = (X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n)$, be random sample , where $X_{i} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$. Show that:

$$U:= \frac{n-1}{\sigma^2} S^2 \sim \chi^2 (n-1); \text{ where } S^2:= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2.$$

Do I need to prove first that the statistic, the sample mean, is sufficient? Or show the independence through Basu's Theorem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can someone explain _why_ some people want to close this question?  It looks like a reasonable question to me. $\qquad$

Comment: This question is about an issue of importance in the theory of statistics. The poster with some specificity gives his thoughts on how to solve the problem. It appears to be a good question. Is there something I'm missing when I don't understand why three people want to close it?  Are they not able to explain that in comments here?  They haven't tried to do so. $\qquad$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance

Answer (score 2):

If $\sigma^2$ is “known”, then the sample mean is sufficient.  In other words, for the family of distributions you get by letting $\mu$ vary with $\sigma^2$ fixed, the sample mean is sufficient.  But Basu's theorem relies on completeness, so you'd have to prove completeness before you know that Basu's theorem is applicable.  I think it could be done that way, but I haven't worked out the details.

But to show independence of $\overline X$ and $S^2$, you can first work on proving these two random variables are independent of each other:
$$
\overline X \quad \text{and} \quad 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} X_1 - \overline X \\  \vdots \\  X_n - \overline X \end{array} \right]. \tag 1
$$
That doesn't require Basu's theorem.  Try finding covariances.

But your question as initially phrased asks about something other than independence, namely the distribution of $S^2$.  I don't know why you would think Basu's theorem could help with that.

The mapping that takes the vector
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} X_1 \\  \vdots \\  X_n \end{array} \right] \tag 2
$$
to the vector in $(1)$ is the orthogonal projection onto an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace, and it maps the expected value
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} \mu \\  \vdots \\ \mu \end{array} \right]
$$
to a vector of $n$ zeros.  The distribution of $(2)$ is spherically symmetric in $n$ space; therefore it is the same as the distribution of $[ U_1,\ldots, U_n]^T$, where that vector expresses the vector $(1)$ with respect to a certain alternative basis of $\mathbb R^n$.  That alternative basis consists of $n-1$ mutually orthogonal unit vectors in the space onto which one is projecting, and one unit vector at a right angle to that.  With respect to that basis, the projection is
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} U_1 \\ U_2 \\ U_3 \\ \vdots \\ U_n \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ U_2 \\ U_3 \\ \vdots \\ U_n \end{array} \right].
$$
The first component simply becomes $0$ and the rest are unchanged.  Therefore we have
$$
(X_1-\overline X)^2 + \cdots + (X_n - \overline X)^2 = \underbrace{U_2^2 + \cdots + U_n^2}_\text{starting with 2, not with 1}.
$$
So
$$
\frac 1 {\sigma^2} (U_2^2 + \cdots + U_n^2) \sim \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$